# Spring boot add criteria query

Tags: java, regex, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

When Deal Type is Rate $ it is not searching/getting but when deal type is Rate % it is working.

```
if(promotionInput.getDealType() != null) {
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(PromotionMasterConstants.DEAL_TYPE_DB).regex(promotionInput.getDealType(),"i"));
        }
```

I am not getting the error.

Comment: `promotionInput.getDealType()` is returning regex expression with dollar sign ?

Comment: In UI when trying to filter the deal type as Rate $ its not getting/no result, and for Rate % its searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are providing regex pattern (`promotionInput.getDealType()` in this case) without escaping special regex characters.

Special regex metacharacters: `., +, *, ?, ^, $, (, ), [, ], {, }, |, \.`

In your situation, `promotionInput.getDealType()` contains unescaped dollar sign that you should escape before providing a regex search.

> **If a dollar sign ($) is at the end of the entire regular expression, it matches the end of a line.**
>
> **If an entire regular expression is enclosed by a caret and dollar sign (^like this$), it matches an entire line.**

```java
if(promotionInput.getDealType() != null) {

   // maybe check for other metacharacters?
   String escapedDealType = promotionInput.getDealType().replace("$", "\\$");

   query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(PromotionMasterConstants.DEAL_TYPE_DB)
                    .regex(escapedDealType,"i"));
}
```

#### Data in MongoDB

```sh
rs0:PRIMARY> db.promotion.find()
        { "_id" : ObjectId("6034bbfee56ebe09e8821e44"), "value" : "Rate $", "_class" : "com.xyz.model.Promotion" }
        { "_id" : ObjectId("6034bbfee56ebe09e8821e45"), "value" : "Rate %", "_class" : "com.xyz.model.Promotion" }
```

#### Test: Searching the value with regex

Test is executed successfully and green.

```java
@Test
    public void name() {

        // drop everything
        mongoTemplate.dropCollection(Promotion.class);

        // persist entity with value field equls to "Rate $"
        final Promotion promotion = new Promotion();
        promotion.setValue("Rate $");
        mongoTemplate.insert(promotion);

        // persist entity with value field equls to "Rate %"
        final Promotion promotion2 = new Promotion();
        promotion2.setValue("Rate %");
        mongoTemplate.insert(promotion2);

        // RETURNS EMPTY COLLECTION
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("value").regex("Rate $", "i"));
        List<Promotion> promotions = mongoTemplate.find(query, Promotion.class);
        assertThat(promotions.size(), is(0));

        // query with escaped $
        // FINDS THE RECORD SUCCESSFULLY
        Query query2 = new Query();
        query2.addCriteria(Criteria.where("value").regex("Rate \\$", "i"));
        promotions = mongoTemplate.find(query2, Promotion.class);
        assertThat(promotions.size(), is(1));
        assertThat(promotions.get(0).getValue(), is("Rate $"));
    }
```

Comment: replaceAll is adding a $...That is Rate $$. But i need to search only not replace.

Comment: Yes, indeed I changed `replaceAll` to `replace` now it's escaping `$`.  BTW, the code does not change the value of `promotionInput.getDealType()`, instead assigns it to local variable `escapedDealType`. (String is immutable in Java)  Then providing the escaped string to the mongo regex search.

Comment: This is giving dealType as "Rate \\$"

Comment: Yes, I know the output. What I'm trying to say is you are providing `regex(REGEX PATTERN WITH DOLLAR SIGN,"i"))`, and I'm saying you should escape that. You are saying it works when `promotionInput.getDealType()` with `Rate %`, but `Rate $`... What is the actual data you are trying to search, could you enhance your question with more details ?

Comment: I  want to search for Rate $. But when I am searching Rate % its working correctly.

Comment: I have Promotion database in which deal Type is Rate %, Rate $. I am trying to search for Rate $ but its not getting in the database.

Answer (score 0):

if(promotionInput.getDealType() != null) {

query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(PromotionMasterConstants.DEAL_TYPE_DB).regex(promotionInput.getDealType().replace("$", "\$"),"i"));
}

It will take Rate $